# Why is Aperture showing thousands of Rejected, but there are only 3 there?

Tags: macos, aperture

My Aperture is showing 2.5k Rejected photos (count), but when I view the album, there are only 3 there. I tried rebuilding the database.

I also tried switching and viewing the library in iPhoto, which shows no hidden photos. The library in Aperture shows no hidden photos. When I create a Smart Album having only Rejected items in it, it still only shows 3 items.

My Trash is empty too, and permissions are correct.

Any ideas on what's wrong, and why it's showing this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently aperture doesn't show photos that have been hidden in iPhoto. You need to open the library in iPhoto and unhide them there, I think. Then you can reject them in aperture again, and they should show up as expected.